# Error while installing mysqlclient in django project on cPanel

Tags: python, gcc, cpanel, mysql-connector

I've been trying to solve this problem for a couple of days. I am trying to put my Django project in a venv on cPanel and install mysqlclient. So after setting up my Python (version = 3.7.8) on Cpanel, I installed Django version 3.1.7 and mysqlclient from the terminal using `pip install django` and `pip install mysqlclient`. However when I try to install mysqlclient, this error pops out.

````
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.0.3.tar.gz (88 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/canggihmallmy/virtualenv/django_test/3.7/bin/python3.7_bin -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ct08p_k4/mysqlclient_5cd61bc8b4de40efb5731cfe082b4d65/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ct08p_k4/mysqlclient_5cd61bc8b4de40efb5731cfe082b4d65/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-scx4wswm
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ct08p_k4/mysqlclient_5cd61bc8b4de40efb5731cfe082b4d65/
  Complete output (43 lines):
  mysql_config --version
  ['10.0.38']
  mysql_config --libs
  ['-L/usr/lib64', '-lmysqlclient', '-lpthread', '-lz', '-lm', '-ldl', '-lssl', '-lcrypto']
  mysql_config --cflags
  ['-I/usr/include/mysql', '-I/usr/include/mysql/..']
  ext_options:
    library_dirs: ['/usr/lib64']
    libraries: ['mysqlclient', 'pthread', 'm', 'dl']
    extra_compile_args: ['-std=c99']
    extra_link_args: []
    include_dirs: ['/usr/include/mysql', '/usr/include/mysql/..']
    extra_objects: []
    define_macros: [('version_info', "(2,0,3,'final',0)"), ('__version__', '2.0.3')]
  /opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(2,0,3,'final',0) -D__version__=2.0.3 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/.. -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -std=c99
  unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/canggihmallmy/virtualenv/django_test/3.7/bin/python3.7_bin -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ct08p_k4/mysqlclient_5cd61bc8b4de40efb5731cfe082b4d65/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ct08p_k4/mysqlclient_5cd61bc8b4de40efb5731cfe082b4d65/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"','"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-1wxueu88/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/canggihmallmy/virtualenv/django_test/3.7/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ct08p_k4/mysqlclient_5cd61bc8b4de40efb5731cfe082b4d65/
    Complete output (43 lines):
    mysql_config --version
    ['10.0.38']
    mysql_config --libs
    ['-L/usr/lib64', '-lmysqlclient', '-lpthread', '-lz', '-lm', '-ldl', '-lssl', '-lcrypto']
    mysql_config --cflags
    ['-I/usr/include/mysql', '-I/usr/include/mysql/..']
    ext_options:
      library_dirs: ['/usr/lib64']
      libraries: ['mysqlclient', 'pthread', 'm', 'dl']
      extra_compile_args: ['-std=c99']
      extra_link_args: []
      include_dirs: ['/usr/include/mysql', '/usr/include/mysql/..']
      extra_objects: []
      define_macros: [('version_info', "(2,0,3,'final',0)"), ('__version__', '2.0.3')]
    /opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(2,0,3,'final',0) -D__version__=2.0.3 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/.. -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -std=c99
    unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/canggihmallmy/virtualenv/django_test/3.7/bin/python3.7_bin -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ct08p_k4/mysqlclient_5cd61bc8b4de40efb5731cfe082b4d65/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ct08p_k4/mysqlclient_5cd61bc8b4de40efb5731cfe082b4d65/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-1wxueu88/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/canggihmallmy/virtualenv/django_test/3.7/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output. ```

I have tried some of the guide from , such as `yum install mysql` and sudo commands but to no avail.

Please help.
````

Comment: Hi, I voted to close this question because it's not about programming but rather about 'sysadmin' stuff, so it should go on Serverfault.com.

That said, it seems like on your hosting plan you are not allowed to use `gcc` which is required for installing Python modules that use C-libraries. Please check with your hosting provider if they offer a workaround. Also, you MIGHT be able to get around this by using a 'python-only' client, check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers

Comment: Noted @MichielB. I will take it down soon and refer to serverfault.com instead. Thank you

Comment: @codingnoob have you solved it? i am in stuck in it.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. After days of research I found this solution. I hope this works with your problem too.

## Terminal

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

## settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'DATEBASE_NAME',
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'USER': 'USERNAME',
        'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD',
        'OPTIONS': {
          'autocommit': True,
        },
    }
}
```

## Terminal

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```